# Remaining seconds until bar close - pine script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to calculate the remaining seconds in real time until the bar closes.

I did this:

"
timeLeft = barstate.isrealtime ?
     (time_close - timenow) / 1000 :
     na

secLeft = floor(timeLeft)

plot(series=secLeft, title="Seconds left")
"

But the problem is that timenow is not updated often enough (I have calc_on_every_tick=true) and  because of that the seconds are not in real time.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiqQx.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can check remaining time until bar close in chart settings / scales /countdown until bar close

Answer (score 0):

Your technique is sound, but see the usrman on [execution in the realtime bar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-realtime-bars).

Execution of Pine scripts in the realtime bar is event-driven. When no user action (like a change in the script's *Inputs*) causes a re-execution, it requires a price or volume update to be detected on the feed, which happens at random intervals.

Comment: Shouldn't "timenow" be script's input?

Comment: No. Won't work. `timenow` is the current time in ms.

Comment: No. While it's precision is in ms, in the realtime bar it's updated like I explained in the answer. When the script is executing on historical bars it's only updated every second. You can see this in action with our [Script Stopwatch - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/rRmrkRDr-Script-Stopwatch-PineCoders-FAQ/).